# jquery function doesn't work on second page of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, pagination

I am currently making a table with data coming from a database via sql and i am generating each row with the following code:

```
<tbody>
<?php
foreach($merchants as $merchant) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $merchant['id'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $merchant['name'] . '</td>';
   if ($userIsAdmin){
       echo '<td>' . date("d.m.Y" , strtotime($merchant['import_date'])) . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $merchant['import_from'] . '</td>';
   }
   echo '<td>' . $merchant['number_keys'] . '</td>';
   if ($userIsAdmin){
       echo '<td><a class="merchantDelete" href="#" data-id="' . $merchant['id'] . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteMerchantModal">
             <i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
             <a class="merchantEdit" href="#" data-name="' . $merchant['name'] . '" data-hidden="' . $merchant['id'] . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editMerchantModal">
             <i class="far fa-edit"></i></a><input type="text" value="' . $merchant['id'] . '" hidden></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
```

The elements with class `merchantDelete` and `merchantEdit` are buttons to delete or edit data in the database. The modals are to check what data should be edited and what should be deleted. I am using **`data-xxx`** to pass the data needed to the following modal.(I am only showing 1 modal because the principle is the same)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editMerchantModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Merchant</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
             </div>
             <form method="POST" action="action_merchants.php<?php echo '?location=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <input type="hidden" name="action2" value="edit">
                     <div class="form-row">
                         <div class="col-4">
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="hidden" id="modal_hidden" value="">
                             </div>
                             <label for="select_m" class="col-form lable">Curent Name:</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="select" id="select_m" disabled>
                             <label for="new_name" class="col-form lable">New Name:</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="new_name" id="new_name"
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="new_merchants_submit" value="Edit">
                    </div>
              </form>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i am passing the previously mentioned values to the modal with this jquery function:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".merchantEdit").click(function () {
            var name_value = $(this).data('name');
            var hidden_value = $(this).data('hidden');
            $('#select_m').val(name_value);
            $('#modal_hidden').val(hidden_value);
            $('#new_name').val(name_value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works how it should, however only on the first page of my table. I am using ajax to change page. Now the problem is that the function doesnt ever run when i am on the second page, even tho the elements  .merchantEdit  and  .merchantDelete have the correct data-values.

I have been researching for a while now, but i couldn't get it to work. 
I would apreciate any help i could get.

Thanks,

Matt.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the click is listening for the elements already rendered to the DOM, Try using

```
$(document).on("click",".merchantEdit",function() {
        var name_value = $(this).data('name');
        var hidden_value = $(this).data('hidden');
        $('#select_m').val(name_value);
        $('#modal_hidden').val(hidden_value);
        $('#new_name').val(name_value);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. this worked perfectly.